# VBA code not running with big amount of data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why the code is not running when I try to use it for a big set of data. I need to do a transposition per batches of 144000 data points from rows to columns.
I did a trial for working with a VBA code that allows me to do a transposition per batches of data from 2RX5C to 5RX2C. the code works:

```
Sub Macro1()

End Sub
Sub transpose()
'
' transpose Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
    Range("A1:E2").Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:E2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, transpose:=True

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(5, -7).Range("A1:E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, transpose:=True
  Loop
        
End Sub
```

However, when I adequate the code for working with 24RX56C to 56RX24C, the code does not run once I include **Do until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)** and **Loop**. (It skips all the code between these two)

```
Sub TRANSPOSE()
'
' TRANSPOSE Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
    Range("B2:BE25").Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:BD24").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 60).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, TRANSPOSE:=True

   Do until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)   
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=57
    ActiveCell.Offset(56, -60).Range("A1:BD24").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 60).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, TRANSPOSE:=True
   Loop     
End Sub

I am stuck for a month now and I would appreciate any help.
```

Comment: You may want to see [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). It will help clean up the code tremendously.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but why don't you just open a second Worksheet, and use the TRANSPOSE() worksheet function? If you have a recent Excel version it will automatically fill the target cells for you. Using Select, Copy, Paste is fraught with problems.

Comment: @BigBen thank you for answer. the main issue is when I insert the Do until isempty argument.

Comment: @DS_London, I tried your suggestion but because the data should be transposed per batches the columns are not enough for working with the entire dataset, and also the data is transposed uniformly and not per batches. :(

Answer (score 1):

Macro recorder is not much use for something like this - you need to read up a little on how to set and manipulate `Range` variables, in addition to avoiding Select/Activate

```vb
Sub TRANSPOSE()

    Dim rng As Range, rngP As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:BE25")                    'source range
    Set rngP = rng.Cells(1).Offset(0, rng.Columns.Count + 1)  'destination range
    
    Do While Len(rng.Cells(1).Value) > 0
        rng.Copy
        rngP.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
             Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, TRANSPOSE:=True
        
        'offset source and destination ranges
        Set rng = rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count, 0)
        Set rngP = rngP.Offset(rng.Columns.Count, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```